# How to use javascript click to trigger POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-push

When a user clicks...

```
<%= content_tag(:button, "Send", class: "webpush-button") %>
# Previous Attempt: <%= button_to 'send', class: "webpush-button" %>

<script>
  $('.webpush-button').on('click', (e) => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
    .then((serviceWorkerRegistration) => {
      serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
      .then((subscription) => {
        $.post("/post", {
          subscription: subscription.toJSON(),
          message: 'You clicked a button!'
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

he should be taken through...

```
class PushNotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def push
    Webpush.payload_send(
      message: params[:message],
      endpoint: params[:subscription][:endpoint],
      p256dh: params[:subscription][:keys][:p256dh],
      auth: params[:subscription][:keys][:auth],
      vapid: {
        subject: "mailto:sender@example.com",
        public_key: ENV['VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY'],
        private_key: ENV['VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY']
      }
    )
  end
end
```

but instead nothing happens. The `.webpush-button` javascript never kicks in. I put it in two places and it still has no effect...

**application.js**

```
/ Register the serviceWorker script at /serviceworker.js from our server if supported
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js').then(function(reg) {
    console.log('Service worker change, registered the service worker');
  });
}
// Otherwise, no push notifications :(
else {
  console.error('Service worker is not supported in this browser');
}

// When serviceWorker is supported, installed, and activated,
// subscribe the pushManager property with the vapidPublicKey
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((serviceWorkerRegistration) => {
  serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: window.vapidPublicKey
  });
});

$('.webpush-button').on('click', (e) => {
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready
  .then((serviceWorkerRegistration) => {
    serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
    .then((subscription) => {
      $.post('/push', {
        subscription: subscription.toJSON(),
        message: 'You clicked a button!'
      });
    });
  });
});

// Let's check if the browser supports notifications
if (!("Notification" in window)) {
  console.error("This browser does not support desktop notification");
}

// Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
  console.log("Permission to receive notifications has been granted");
}

// Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
  Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
  // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
    if (permission === "granted") {
      console.log("Permission to receive notifications has been granted");
    }
  });
}
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<script>
  window.vapidPublicKey = new Uint8Array("<%= @decodedVapidPublicKey %>");
</script>
```

Now based on the [tutorial](https://rossta.net/blog/using-the-web-push-api-with-vapid.html) and [git](https://github.com/zaru/webpush) code I used... the subscription should be gathered from the [serviceworker](https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails) so then why am I still getting a nil error?

I'm using [serviceworker](https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails) & [webpush](https://github.com/zaru/webpush) gems and followed this VAPID [tutorial](https://rossta.net/blog/using-the-web-push-api-with-vapid.html).

Not a duplicate. The other question is focused on params. This one is focused on javascript not triggering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subscription params nil for web push serviceworker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572177/subscription-params-nil-for-web-push-serviceworker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should only put the javascript at one place.

Second, add the `.webpush-button click` method after page be `ready`

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {

});
```

And in the chrome dev tools, Tab `Event Listeners`, check if the html element has click event.

Comment: Yes it does have click event with `button.webpush-button`. With the adjustment I made from your answer the javascript still doesn't trigger. I also removed the duplication from application.js

Comment: em..you can also add the `console.log` before your method, if it show the log, then the javascript is `triggered`, just your code logic is wrong.